# I don't know how to use urwid.Button

Tags: python, urwid

Hello i'm trying to understand urwid library to make my programs:

I have a problem, when i create a button with: urwid.Button('my button', on_press=function())
or like in the code below:

```
import urwid

def show_or_exit(key):
    if key in ('q', 'Q'):
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()
   
def action():
    print("click")

button = urwid.Button(' Press Enter Key ... ')
urwid.connect_signal(button, 'click', action())
button = urwid.Padding(button, align='center', width=20)
button = urwid.Filler(button, 'middle')

mainloop = urwid.MainLoop(button, unhandled_input=show_or_exit)
mainloop.run()
```

1. the function action is called when i launch the program
2. when i click the button i have an error :
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Any idea ?

Comment: probably in all GUIs you have to assign function's name WITHOUT `()` - and when you press button then it will use `()` to exectute it. It is called `callback`

Comment: frankly, I don't understand you. In `unhandled_input=show_or_exit` you correctly use function's name without `()` but in `urwid.connect_signal(button, 'click', action())` you incorrectly use function's name with `()`

Comment: ok thank you guys, i received an error message without the (), and was thinking it was about ()

Comment: it seems it sends widget/button to function as argument and you have to define it as `def action(widget):` - this way you can assign function to many buttons and you can access clicked button inside function.

Answer (score 0):

`callback` means function's name without `()` and without arguments.

```
urwid.connect_signal(button, 'click', action)  # `action` without `()
```

And when you will press button then it will use `()` to execute this function.

And probably all GUIs need function's name without `()` and without arguments.

---

**EDIT:**

Your code works like

```
result = action()

urwid.connect_signal(button, 'click', result)
```

Because `action()` returns `None` so you have

```
urwid.connect_signal(button, 'click', None)
```

and later it will try to execute `None()`

And this gives `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

---

**EDIT:**

There is other problem in code. `urwid` sends button/widget to this function and you have to get this argument

```
def action(widget):
    #print('widget:', widget)
    #print('label:', widget.label)
    print("click")
```

It sends button and you can assign function to different buttons and inside function you can access pressed button to modify it or get some parameters from button (i.e. get/set text on button).

---

**BTW:**

If you will have to use function which gets arguments then you can use `lambda` to create function without arguments

```
def action(widget, text):
    print(text)

urwid.connect_signal(button, 'click', lambda widget:action(widget, "Hello World"))
```

And if you will have to use `for`-loop to create many buttons then you may need to assign value to variable in lambda:

```
for numr in range(5)
    button = urwid.Button(f'Number {num}')
    urwid.connect_signal(button, 'click', lambda widget,x=num:action(widget, x))  
    # not `lambda widget:action(widget, num)`
```